# Replace content by class via AJAX

Tags: ajax, lift

With lift, if we want to replace the content of some DOM, we can use `SetHtml` if we know the ID of the DOM:

```
SetHtml(domID, Text("new text"))
```

But `SetHtml` only accepts `id`, what if I want to find DOMs by class?

```
SetHtml(".message", Text("new message"))
```

It can't work(of course), what should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use scala jquery DLS, maybe something like this will work?

```
JqJE.Jq(".class") ~> JqJE.JqHtml(Text(""))
```

this basically constructs the same js code that @DrHossein wrote. Also, if you want, you can just use `JsCmds.Run("")` and inline everything you need as raw text.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
$(".somClass").html("new message");
```

Comment: well yes! I didn't notice to "lift". lift has just setHtml for this kind of tasks. sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above should work for you. An alternate option would be to create your own reusable `JsCmd` using the suggested above. This is the code that Lift uses by default for [`SetHtml`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/js/jquery/JqJsCmds.scala#L507)

```
case class JqSetHtml(uid: String, content: NodeSeq) extends JsCmd {
  /**
   * Eagerly evaluate
   */
  val toJsCmd = (JqJE.JqId(JE.Str(uid)) ~> JqJE.JqHtml(content)).cmd.toJsCmd
}
```

So, if you wanted to adopt it for a generic html class, you could do something like:

```
case class JqSetHtmlByClass(className: String, content: NodeSeq) extends JsCmd {
  val toJsCmd = (JqJE.JqId(JE.Str(className)) ~> JqJE.JqHtml(content)).cmd.toJsCmd
}
```